# Виртуальный сервер, сбой в работе скрипта загрузки файлов через форму

Tags: php, openserver, сервер

Здравствуйте!

Тут возникла проблема с двумя виртуальными серверами - это с OpenServer и denwer. Сначала я пробовал скрипт из учебника Прохоренок Н.А. - HTML, JavaScript, PHP и MySQL. Джентльменский набор Web-мастера (Профессиональное программирование) - 2010 на стр. 566, скрипт испытывал на denvwer, вот сам скрипт:

```
Листинг 5.48. Содержимое файла file_load.html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Загрузка файлов</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-
1251">
</head>
<body>
<h1>Загрузка файлов</h1>
<form action="file.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div>
<input type="file" name="file_name" size="20">
<input type="submit" value="Загрузить">
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Это форма, которая должна обратиться к следующему листенгу:

Далее создаем файл file.php и добавляем в него код, представленный в лис-тинге 5.49. Основы PHP. Создаем динамические Web-страницы 567 Листинг 5.49. Содержимое файла file.php:

```
<?php
if (isset($_FILES['file_name'])) {
if ($_FILES['file_name']['error'] == 0 &&
$_FILES['file_name']['size'] > 0) {
$path = "C:\\Apache2\\htdocs\\";
$path .= basename($_FILES['file_name']['name']);
if (@move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file_name']['tmp_name'], $path)) {
echo 'Файл загружен';
}
else {
echo 'Ошибка при загрузке';
}
}
else echo 'Ошибка при загрузке';
}
?>
```

Всё бы ничего, но на обоих серверах даже на OpenServer

> ошибка загрузки файла

**Подскажите почему?**

У меня у самого предположение: может, Apache нужно настраивать, или я что-то не включил на серверах? Побовал похожие скрипты в Интернете - та же ситуация, подскажите, помогите, что не так?

Comment: Логи сервера нашёл: 

>saksmart.ru: 127.0.0.1 [09/Feb/2015:10:31:04 +0300] "POST /razdeli/download/loading.php HTTP/1.1" 200 46 "http://saksmart.ru/razdeli/download/file.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; ru-RU; rv:1.8.1.24pre) Gecko/20100228 K-Meleon/1.5.4"
saksmart.ru: 127.0.0.1 [09/Feb/2015:10:34:46 +0300] "POST /razdeli/download/loading.php HTTP/1.1" 200 46 "http://saksmart.ru/razdeli/download/file.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; ru-RU; rv:1.8.1.24pre) Gecko/20100228 K-Meleon/1.5.4"

Comment: ииии... смысл то в этих логах какой? никакого правильно. я дал ссылку на мануал где написано

Returns TRUE on success.

If filename is not a valid upload file, then no action will occur, and move_uploaded_file() will return FALSE.

If filename is a valid upload file, but cannot be moved for some reason, no action will occur, and move_uploaded_file() will return FALSE. Additionally, a warning will be issued.

есть даже пример там, как обработать ошибку.

Comment: Я в в php немного нуб, покажи, что и как, я хочу понять, как это работает... 

    $path .= basename($_FILES['file_name']['name']);
    if (@move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file_name']['tmp_name'], $path)) {
    echo 'Файл загружен';
    }
    else {
    echo 'Ошибка при загрузке '; 

Что подставить куда, чтобы ошибку поймать?

Мне главное понять, как фаил грузиться, а дальше я сам .... И чтоб загрузился, помоги...

Comment: Возьми пример из мануала. там обработка на загружаемый файл, проверь можно ли писать в директорию куда ты хочешь закинуть файл.
Если файл загрузился в tmp хорошо, но не загрузился в папку - дело в папке.

Comment: В TMP фаил загружается, после загрузки его полной есть попытка его записать в папку и всё тщетно и тогда из временной директории фаил удаляется.

Answer (score 2):

```
$path = "C:\\Apache2\\htdocs\\";
```

Зачем указывать такие пути?

Почему не прописать от корня сайта папку?

```
 $path=(__DIR__).'/files';
```

Ну хотя бы так.

**Обновление**

```
echo 'Ошибка при загрузке';
}
}
else echo 'Ошибка при загрузке';
```

Какая именно ошибка?! Первая вторая... Ну зачем называть 2 разных выхода одинаково?

Может, у тебя файл кривой, а ты и не догадываешься, может, еще что-то.

Назови ты их по-разному хоть.

Если

```
if ($_FILES['file_name']['error'] == 0 &&
$_FILES['file_name']['size'] > 0) {
```

то одна ошибка.

Если

```
if (@move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file_name']['tmp_name'], $path))
```

то другая...

Ошибки-то разные!

Comment: Пути в учебнике прописаны.... Почитай.. Попробую сейчас прописать от корня сайта как говориш папку....

Comment: выброси денвер на помойку - он уже не поддерживается даже автором!

и перестаньте читать книги, которые написаны для дошколят. читайте официальные мануалы!!!

Comment: Не не выходит - Ошибка при загрузке , не грузиться фаил...

Comment: Я сейчас не на denwere, а на OpenServer, последняя версия...

Comment: Возникает у тебя первое исключение `$_FILES['file_name']['error']`, т.к. ерора нет в массиве файлов!

Comment: НЕ ошибка возникает здесь echo 'Файл загружен';
}
else {
echo 'Ошибка при загрузке ';

Логи сервера нашёл


saksmart.ru: 127.0.0.1 [09/Feb/2015:10:34:46 +0300] "POST /razdeli/download/loading.php HTTP/1.1" 200 46 "http://saksmart.ru/razdeli/download/file.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; ru-RU; rv:1.8.1.24pre) Gecko/20100228 K-Meleon/1.5.4"

Comment: ну так выведи ту ошибку, которая возникает в этом IF! Но не спрашивай, как ее получить. [мануал][1]


  [1]: https://php.net/manual/ro/function.move-uploaded-file.php